# Не работает модальное окно на bootsrtap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Подскажите в чём может быть дело.Jquery подключен, обращение по айди.

```html
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

      <a class="button button--pink" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" >Оставить заявку</a> 

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: bootstrap.js не подключен

Comment: Вы не подключили сам bootstrap 4.Найдите в документации как это сделать

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ (docs) - https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ (cdn)

Answer (score 0):

Ты подключил только Jquery. Подключи ещё Bootstrap.js